# Hundreds of Azure Functions under common domain

Tags: azure, azure-functions, hosting

I have a deployment of several hundred Azure Functions that I would like to have accessible under my domain. I can see in the Azure Portal that for each function, I can individually hook it up with a custom domain by adding an A and TXT record to point to that specific function. This works great but does not scale at all.

What I would like to achieve is that I can freely start and stop functions (named let's say `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` etc.) and have them automatically accessible under a subdomain of the domain I have. Like for example: `a.my.domain`, `b.my.domain`, etc. From what I see I would have to add A and TXT records for each `a.my.domain`, `b.my.domain`...

Is there any way I can solve it in some generic fashion? Like adding A and TXT record for just `my.domain` and have the Azure do the magic to route `{name}.my.domain` to function named `{name}`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You looked into APIM?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, multiple function app domains should be under a common domain.
For this, Application Gateway helps to configure multiple domains in single domain with the help of Path based routing concept.

[image]

You can configure the different Azure Function Apps URLs/domains with different paths under the same domain name which redirects every azure function app domain to its respective site.

As @*Skin* Suggested to look into APIM:

> From the Domain Registrar, Configure the APIM Gateway IP Address with the A record or any other [Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-overview) Server.

**References:**

1. MS Q&A #[1065676](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1065676/use-my-domain-url-to-call-an-azure-function) for more information provided by @*MayankBaragali-MSFT*
2. [MS Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-serverless-api-with-functions-api-management/) for configuring the multiple function apps under one domain (APIM).